# embedded function not returning correct value based on variable passing python3

Tags: python, list, function, if-statement, nested-lists

I'm trying to program basic black jack strategy. I would like for my program to return the proper move depending on the dealer's up card and the players 2 cards from the start of the game. I have put together a simple function to handle the player cards that are being passed in, inside a function to handle the dealer card and the player cards.

```
def player_has(card_sets, player_cards):
    for card_set in card_sets:
        if (card_set[0] and card_set[1]) in player_cards:
            return True

    return False

def get_best_move(player_cards, dealer_card):
        move = ''
    if dealer_card == 2 or dealer_card == 3 or dealer_card == 4 and \
            player_has([[2, 2], [3, 3], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9], [11, 11]], player_cards):
        print('split')

    elif dealer_card == 2 or dealer_card == 3 or dealer_card == 4 and player_has([[4, 4]], player_cards):
        print('Hit')

    elif dealer_card == 2 or dealer_card == 3 or dealer_card == 4 and player_has([[5, 5]], player_cards):
        print('Double Down')

    elif dealer_card == 2 or dealer_card == 3 or dealer_card == 4 and player_has([[10, 10]], player_cards):
        print('Stand')

    print(move)
    return move


_player_cards = [10, 10]
_dealer_card = 3
get_best_move(_player_cards, _dealer_card)
```

The problem is that this test should return the elif statement with the values [10, 10] in them, or print('stand'). But instead it is returning the if statement at the top that does not include the combination of player cards 10 and 10.

Comment: `if (card_set[0] or card_set[1]) in player_cards` is not doing what you think it is doing

Comment: yeah i have also used if (card_set[0] and card_set[1]) in player_cards but still get the same result.

Comment: You want `if (card_set[0] in player_cards) or (card_set[1] in player cards)`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some parenthesis in your boolean expressions.

In the main `if` statements, you want to put parenthesis around all of the `or`s, like:

```
if (dealer_card == 2 or dealer_card == 3 or dealer_card == 4) and ..
```

Otherwise, the `and` takes precedence over the `or`s.

As pointed out in a comment, you want:

```
if (card_set[0] in player_cards) or (card_set[1] in player_cards):
```

Rather than what you have, because you want to check `in` twice.

See the [operator precedence section of the Python docs for more info](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).